マルチスライドを自動でスライドさせたい
javascriptを使用して左右に配置した画像を上下対比するように自動スライドさせたいです。
また、より良い作成方法があれば教えていただきたいです。
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>スライド</title>
    <!-- css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/ress/dist/ress.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/multiscroll.js/0.2.2/jquery.multiscroll.css">
</head>

<body class="top-page">
    <!-- <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="logo-items">
                <a href=""><img src="images/王道のみPOP版-王道.png" alt=""></a>
                <a href=""><img src="images/DEEPのみPOP版-王道.png" alt=""></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header> -->

    <main>


        <div id="slider">

            <div class="ms-left">
                <div class="ms-section" id="left1"></div>
                <div class="ms-section" id="left2"></div>
                <div class="ms-section" id="left3"></div>
                <div class="ms-section" id="left4"></div>
                <div class="ms-section" id="left5"></div>
                <div class="ms-section" id="left6"></div>
            </div>


            <div class="ms-right">
                <div class="ms-section" id="right1"></div>
                <div class="ms-section" id="right2"></div>
                <div class="ms-section" id="right3"></div>
                <div class="ms-section" id="right4"></div>
                <div class="ms-section" id="right5"></div>
                <div class="ms-section" id="right6"></div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/multiscroll.js/0.2.2/jquery.multiscroll.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js"></script>
        
    </main>
</body>

</html>

CSS
@charset "utf-8";

    /*左エリア画像設定*/
    #left1 {
        background: url("..//images/thumb01.jpg") no-repeat center;
        background-size: cover;
    }

    #left2 {
        background: url("..//images/thumb02.jpg ") no-repeat center;
        background-size: cover;
    }

    #left3 {
        background: url("..//images/thumb03.jpg") no-repeat center;
        background-size: cover;
    }

    #left4 {
        background: url("..//images/thumb04.jpg") no-repeat center;
        background-size: cover;
    }

    #left5 {
        background: url("..//images/thumb05.jpg") no-repeat center;
        background-size: cover;
    }

    #left6 {
        background: url("..//images/thumb01.jpg") no-repeat center;
        background-size: cover;
    }

    /*右エリア画像設定*/

    #right1 {
        background: url("..//images/thumb05.jpg") no-repeat center;
        background-size: cover;
    }

    #right2 {
        background: url("..//images/thumb04.jpg") no-repeat center;
        background-size: cover;
    }

    #right3 {
        background: url("..//images/thumb03.jpg") no-repeat center;
        background-size: cover;
    }

    #right4 {
        background: url("..//images/thumb02.jpg") no-repeat center;
        background-size: cover;
    }

    #right5 {
        background: url("..//images/thumb01.jpg") no-repeat center;
        background-size: cover;
    }

    #right6 {
        background: url("..//images/thumb05.jpg") no-repeat center;
        background-size: cover;
    }

JS
  $('#slider').multiscroll({
    scrollingSpeed: 2000,
    anchors: ['area1', 'area2', 'area3','area4','area5','area6'],
  navigation: false,
  loopTop: true,
  loopBottom: true,
});

